# Can I use Alexa voice recognition in my iOS and Android app?

Tags: android, ios, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I am looking for a (fast) voice to text recognition api but would prefer to stay within aws, as long as I can do so without sacrificing voice recognition quality.

In looking at the Alexa Voice API and tutorials, they seem to focus on the echo. Does it also work on iOS/Android and is it still as responsive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Alexa Voice Service allows you to embed Alexa - the digital assistant - in your mobile app.  I don't believe there is any way to just use the voice recognition - that's certainly not what it is for.

But a few months ago they broke out some of the services used by Alexa into public services available via AWS ([see here](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-ai/)).  Of these, note that Lex 'provides the advanced deep learning functionalities of automatic speech recognition (ASR) for converting speech to text, and NLU...'. 
 So that is what you are after.

As to how good it is, well, all I can say is that it is desiged to do what you are after and (given the emphasis that Amazon is putting on Alexa and Alexa's dependence on these services) I'm sure it is state-of-the-art and I would suggest that it is in a state of frequent improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Transcribe is an automatic speech recognition (ASR) service that makes it easy for developers to add speech-to-text capability

Follow link:-
https://aws.amazon.com/transcribe/